# Get camera location/angle from viewport in scripting

Tags: scripting, 3d-view, camera

Blender 3.3, I'm going to use scripting to adjust the location of my camera for a render so I'd like to try out a few camera positions and angles. I want to scroll around a viewport to get the right view and then determine the viewport's camera's location and angle so I can set the camera used for rendering to those values later.

But I can't work out what scripting call to make to get the view location/angle from the current viewport. Anyone assist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never found out how to do this, but as a compromise I have scrolled the viewport to the view I want and used Ctrl-Alt-Num0 which moves the camera to that view, so I can then read the location and angle from the camera.

I'm sure somewhere in the object model is the location and angle of the viewport onto the view, but there's too big a data tree for me to find it directly so this compromise will do.